# Find quantiles of a specified beta distribution in R

Tags: r, quantile, percentile

I know that some random variable X is distributed as X ~ Beta(p,q). I want to find values of this distribution corresponding to the 90th and 95th percentiles. The function quantile() in R requires that you enter a data vector, but I specifically want to compute these quantiles without needing to generate an enormous sample from this distribution to plug into the quantile() function.

Is there a way to do this by just specifying the parameters of the beta distribution?

Comment: `help("qbeta")`

Answer (score 1):

```
p <- c(0.90, 0.95)
> qbeta(p = p, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 2) # put your parameters in here
[1] 0.6837722 0.7763932)
```